# Certificate Revocation List in Tomcat6

Tags: openssl, tomcat6, authentication

I have implemented Client Authentication to my Tomcat Server. I have distributed client X509 certificates and JKS which were generated using my own CA crt and openSSL. Now i want to use CRL to block some of my clients. How to add a CRL to tomcat?...I dont find any help from Google on this.

Comment: Any reason you tagged this with `openssl`? It sounds like you're not using the APR.

Comment: actually am using openssl for generating client certificates and managing them..so thought openssl is also related..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am answering my own question. In Tomcat `Connector` tag you have `crlFile` parameter which can be generated using `openssl`. The commands looks some thing like this:

```
openssl ca -config openssl.my.cnf -revoke certs/server.crt
openssl ca -config openssl.my.cnf -gencrl -out crl/myca.crl
```

And the file `myca.crl` is to be updated in `Connector` tag of Tomcat which looks something like this:

```xml
<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           port="8443"
           SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150"
           scheme="https"
           secure="true"
           clientAuth="true"
           sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="one.mamoi.semdev.com.pkcs12"
           keystoreType="PKCS12"
           keystorePass="changeit"
           truststoreFile="server.truststore"
           truststorePass="changeit"
           truststoreType="JKS"
           crlFile="/home/ubuntu/myCA/crl/myca.crl"/>
```

Comment: In your case you need to block only specific clients, what if the CRL list gets updated which is maintained by trusted CA?