# How to add CRL file for Client-Authentication in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat6, authentication

I have implemented Client Authentication in Tomcat6. I wanted to add CRL file to the server. How to do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had same problem. i asked same question as well. Refer this link:

[Certificate Revocation List in Tomcat6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493436/certificate-revocation-list-in-tomcat6)

Anyways in tomcat `Connector` tag you have `crlFile` parameter which can be generated using openssl. The commands looks some thing like this

```
openssl ca -config openssl.my.cnf -revoke certs/server.crt
openssl ca -config openssl.my.cnf -gencrl -out crl/myca.crl
```

And the file `myca.crl` is to be updated in `Connector` tag of Tomcat which looks something like this:

```xml
<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           port="8443"
           SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150"
           scheme="https"
           secure="true"
           clientAuth="true"
           sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="one.mamoi.semdev.com.pkcs12"
           keystoreType="PKCS12"
           keystorePass="changeit"
           truststoreFile="server.truststore"
           truststorePass="changeit"
           truststoreType="JKS"
           crlFile="/home/ubuntu/myCA/crl/myca.crl"/>
```

Comment: Do I need to add any extra tag in the connector to implement CRL cache in the clients web browser(so that if at some point CA server is unavailable it can verify from the revocation list from the cache) ??